# Dynamic time PAge for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a wordpress theme.

I have created a page.php for dynamic page post and other other content.

Now I want to create a time showing page which only show time.

I have .html code for this but I am confused for that which .php I will create for this.

Note: my page and time showing page css are totally difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating a template file for this **any_name.php** in theme root directory.

Start by inserting following code in the file.

```
<?php
  /*
    Template Name: Time
    */
get_header();

your Code Here

get_footer();
```

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/